# Get names of couchbase nodes from Bucket

Tags: python, nodes, couchbase, bucket

I'm trying to get the hostnames of all nodes which are used by my bucket. I want to do that dynamically, as my application is going to run on different server setups.

I thought about getting them via the bucket in my code.

By `.stats()` I know I can get a lot of statistics. But I could not find the node names there.

Is there a proper way to retreive the Node names used by a bucket via the python api?

Comment: When you connect with the python sdks you'll pass the initial connection details, if you remove or add an node the topology will be automatically updated to your client.  What is your particular use case?  If you are using the sdk in different environments then just pass different node addresses to the library when you boot your server.

Answer (score 1):

http://pythonhosted.org/couchbase/api/couchbase.html#couchbase.bucket.Bucket.server_nodes

Use `bucket.server_nodes`. This will give you a list of `[host:rest_port]` for all nodes in the cluster.